# PHPOffice spreadsheet to PDF export

Tags: laravel, phpoffice

I have some spreadsheets in MS excell. Trying to convert them to PDF by using PHPOffice and mPDF class. I have a problem to create and display footers on every created PDF page

This is working code for creating a PDF from spreadsheet.

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf($pe);

Is there any solution or method i can call after this to generate footers before use save() method?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the footer methods e.g. generate a footer with linenumbers

```
$reader =  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");

$spreadsheet = $reader->load('<path>'); //Path of reader sheet
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setFirstFooter('&C&"-,Bold"Page &P from &N'); //generate Fristfooter
```

There are more header/footer possibility look [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-printer-options-for-excel-files) or [class documentation](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.7.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/HeaderFooter.html)